# When I split the database tasks in different operations, I can not save data in Cloudant with Objective c and Bluemix,

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am trying to store a simple object (a custom class that has two String properties) in a Cloudant DB from an iOS App. So far I am trying to apply the samples for the objective c programming language from the IBM Bluemix documentation.
It does not work, in case when I split the cloudant tasks in different operations.

The code to store an object is from the tutorials and has been reused.
(https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/data/index.html)

For authentication I used the Facebook service on bluemix, this works.

The database(s) in cloudant were successfully automatic created by that code: "autmobiledb" and "_users" and also the creation of a data record worked.

But when I split the clouding tasks in different operations, it does not work and I get some nil objects.

Maybe this is the case, because I am new in objective c.

## This is the Class Structure:

- Model Classes (data to save)

  *CalcData, Automobile, Person, PersonSerializer*
- b) Controller Class (handle couldant)

  *Automobile Controller*
- c) Views (Display on the iOS Device)

  *ViewController*

// Create Connection to the remote database and store sample data -> WORKS

```
- (void) setupIMFDatabase:(NSString *) dbname
{
  // Get reference to data manager
  IMFDataManager *manager = [IMFDataManager sharedInstance];
  NSString *name = @"automobiledb"; //dbname;

  // Information
  NSLog(@"************** Inside Class 'setupIMFDatabase' ***************");

  if( manager != nil )
  {
    NSLog(@"IMFDataManager is not NIL OK %@", manager.description);

    if (self.datastore != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: self.datastore ");
    }

    // Create remote store
    [manager remoteStore:name completionHandler:^(CDTStore *createdStore, NSError *error)
    {

      if(error){
         // Handle error
         NSLog(@"ERROR Time(%@): The REMOTE STORE can NOT be created because: %@", error.description);

      }else{

           CDTStore *store = createdStore;
          NSLog(@"CDTStore created successfully: %@", store.name);
          self.datastore = store;
          NSLog(@"The self.datastore.name is %@ : ", self.datastore.name);

          // Set permissions for current user on a store
          // DB_ACCESS_GROUP_MEMBERS, DB_ACCESS_GROUP_ADMINS
          [manager setCurrentUserPermissions: DB_ACCESS_GROUP_MEMBERS forStoreName: name completionHander:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
              if(error){
                  // Handle error
                  NSLog(@"Cloudant User Permission ERROR: %@", error.description);
              }else{
                  // setting permissions was successful
                  NSLog(@"No ERROR Description available - Cloudant User Permission OK");
            }

            if (success) {
                // Handle error
                NSLog(@"BOOLEAN CHECK: 'success == true' Cloudant User Permission");
            } else {
                // setting permissions was successful
                NSLog(@"BOOLEAN CHECK: 'success == false' Cloudant User Permission");
            }
        }];

        NSLog(@"INSIDE (Create remote store) the self.datastore is not NIL: %@", self.datastore.name);

        CDTDataObjectMapper *mapper = (CDTDataObjectMapper*) self.datastore.mapper;
        if (mapper != nil)
        {
            [mapper setDataType:@"CalcData" forClassName:@"CalcData" ];
            NSLog(@"CDTDataObjectMapper is not NIL The description is: (%@)", mapper.description);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: CDTDataObjectMapper IS NIL");
        }

        // Check the creation inside the setup if the database
        CalcData* myCalcData = [[CalcData alloc] initWithValue:@"1+2=3" theID: @"12345"];
        [self.datastore save:myCalcData completionHandler:^(id savedObject, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"CHECK SAVE during the setup CALC DATA -- START ---");
            if (error) {
                // save was not successful, handler received an error
                NSLog(@"The ERROR description is: (' %@ ')", error.description);
            } else {
                // use the result
                CalcData *savedCalc = savedObject;
                NSLog(@"The saved revision: %@", savedCalc);
                NSLog(@"Data Saved: Value: %@ ID: %@", savedCalc.theCalcValue, savedCalc.theID);

            }
            NSLog(@"CHECK SAVE during the setup CALC DATA -- END ---");
        }];


    }
  }];
  } else {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: IMFDataManager is NIL");
  }

  // Initialize the Mapper
  if (self.datastore != nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"OUTSIDE self.datastore is not NIL: %@", self.datastore.name);

    CDTDataObjectMapper *mapper = (CDTDataObjectMapper*) self.datastore.mapper;
   if (mapper != nil)
   {
     NSLog(@"CDTDataObjectMapper is not NIL OK %@", mapper.description);
    [mapper setDataType:@"CalcData" forClassName:@"CalcData" ];
   } else {
     NSLog(@"ERROR: CDTDataObjectMapper IS NIL");
   }
  } else {
      NSLog(@"ERROR: self.datastore is NIL");
  }
}
```

// Save Item to coudant -> DOES NOT WORK

```
- (void) createItem: (Automobile*) itemToStore
{
 // Use an existing store
 CDTStore *store = self.datastore;

if(store == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR: The CDTStore inside 'createItem' is NIL");
    return;
}

// The ObjectMapper must be a DataObjectMapper instance or a subclass
CDTDataObjectMapper *mapper = (CDTDataObjectMapper*) store.mapper;
if(mapper == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"ERROR: The CDTDataObjectMapper nside 'createItem' is NIL");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"TRY TO SAVE ITEM");


CalcData* myCalcData = [[CalcData alloc] initWithValue:@"1+2=3" theID: @"12345"];

NSLog(@"TRY TO SAVE ITEM: SetDataType");
[mapper setDataType:@"CalcData" forClassName:@"CalcData" ];

[store save:myCalcData completionHandler:^(id savedObject, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"TRY TO CHECK SAVE RESULT CALC-- START ---");
    // save was not successful, handler received an error
    if (error) {
        // save was not successful, handler received an error
        NSLog(@"ERROR CAN NOT STORE DATA: %@", error.description);
    } else {
        // use the result
        CalcData *savedCalc = savedObject;
        NSLog(@"saved revision: %@", savedCalc);
        NSLog(@"Data Saved: Value: %@ ID: %@", savedCalc.theCalcValue, savedCalc.theID);

    }
    NSLog(@"TRY TO CHECK SAVE RESULT CALC DATA -- END ---");
}];
}
```

// Using the controller in the View

```
- (IBAction)saveToBlueMixClick:(id)sender {

 NSLog(@"********************************* INIT CONTROLLER **************");
 AutomobileController* myAutoController = [[AutomobileController alloc]init];

 NSLog(@"********************************* INIT DATABASE   **************");
 NSString *name = @"automobiledb"; //dbname;
 [myAutoController setupIMFDatabase:name];

 NSLog(@"********************************* SAVE ITEM       **************");
 [myAutoController createItem:myAutomobile];
}    
@end
```

## DEBUG INFORMATION:

```
2015-06-02 16:35:46.868 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ********************************* INIT CONTROLLER **************
2015-06-02 16:35:46.869 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ************************  INIT: AutomobileController DATABASE ***********************
2015-06-02 16:35:46.869 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ********************************* INIT DATABASE   **************
2015-06-02 16:35:46.880 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataAuthorizationManager initialized with scope (null)
2015-06-02 16:35:46.888 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataAuthorizationManager registered as an NSURLProtocol
2015-06-02 16:35:46.896 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataAuthorizationManager registering protected resource URL https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455
2015-06-02 16:35:46.932 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] 

IMFDataManager initialized successfully:
CloudantToolkit Version: 1.0.0
CloudantToolkit Build Date: 20150309_1800
IMFData-Bluemix Version: 1.0.0
IMFData-Bluemix Build Date: 20150309_1800
Target URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455

2015-06-02 16:35:46.939 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] 

IMFDataManager initialized successfully:
CloudantToolkit Version: 1.0.0
CloudantToolkit Build Date: 20150309_1800
IMFData-Bluemix Version: 1.0.0
IMFData-Bluemix Build Date: 20150309_1800
Target URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455

2015-06-02 16:35:46.941 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ************** Inside Class 'setupIMFDatabase' ***************
2015-06-02 16:35:46.942 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] IMFDataManager is not NIL OK <IMFDataManager: 0x14d8b980>
2015-06-02 16:35:46.943 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] remoteStore URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
2015-06-02 16:35:46.952 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] CDTHttpHelper.sendHttpRequest:method:headers:payload:completionHandler: making HTTP request.  Details: 
URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
Method: PUT
Headers:
2015-06-02 16:35:46.959 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ERROR: self.datastore is NIL
2015-06-02 16:35:46.961 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ********************************* SAVE ITEM       **************
2015-06-02 16:35:46.962 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] ERROR: The CDTStore inside 'createItem' is NIL
2015-06-02 16:35:46.969 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136599] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataProtocol.sendRequestToProtectedResource: making HTTP request.  Details: 
URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
Method: PUT
Headers:
Authorization : Bearer eyJh **** BIN DATA **** mSGGLrG4_yIBKA
2015-06-02 16:35:47.288 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136599] [INFO] [IMFData] Authorization failure.  Http status 401 received on request to https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
2015-06-02 16:35:47.298 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136599] [INFO] [IMFData] Authorization token invalid.  Requesting new token.
2015-06-02 16:35:47.308 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136599] [INFO] [IMFData] Authorization failure.  Http status 401 received on request to https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
2015-06-02 16:35:47.733 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestRedirected:response:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:235 :: Request Redirected to URL : http://localhost?code=FWO7lxoRjc20cmIG2J1F4xWHu6ErL85RP1maAgNXAC00N5Ao10nxEFXdNkhsDvrdRQFBeF3x-H6xXFaD4jiunp7SUoedMvjfh8fNcfMbYYTnoCCGhf-4bJ4-m9PLOkieu_a3QrEZew02ybFblXP23wJccHLIqWUMtlwGWkwLu-tWrsIsIKIq6dXeFoJfxltc&wl_result=%7B%22WL-Authentication-Success%22:%7B%22wl_facebookRealm%22:%7B%22userId%22:%22707109936101050%22,%22attributes%22:%7B%7D,%22isUserAuthenticated%22:1,%22displayName%22:%22Thomas+Nikolaus+Michael+S%22,%22deviceId%22:%22707109936101050%22%7D%7D%7D
2015-06-02 16:35:47.746 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager handleGrantCode:] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:320 :: Grant code received successfully
2015-06-02 16:35:47.754 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager invokeTokenRequest] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:326 :: Call token endpoint in order to obtain authorization token
2015-06-02 16:35:48.191 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:216 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success
2015-06-02 16:35:48.265 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest makeRequestWithPath:options:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:70 :: Building the request URL with path: authorization/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/token
2015-06-02 16:35:48.271 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:44 :: Request url is https://storeinbluemix.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/token
2015-06-02 16:35:48.280 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF_REQUEST] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest sendRequestToPath:path:withOptions:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:115 :: Request timeout is 60.000000
2015-06-02 16:35:48.292 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF_REQUEST] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest sendRequestToPath:path:withOptions:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:171 :: Sending request (https://storeinbluemix.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/token) with headers: 
{
"Accept-Language" = de;
"User-Agent" = "/StoreInBlueMix/1 (iPad; iOS 8.1.2; Scale/1.00)/IMFAPI";
"X-REWRITE-DOMAIN" = "eu-gb.bluemix.net";
"X-WL-Auth" = 1;
"X-WL-Authenticate" = "eyJhbGci *** BIN DATA +++7mmJZKt5xu-HnO72i-BGYpA==";
"X-WL-Session" = "0152FE04-CEC6-4F65-9148-B94F892A6CE8";
}
Post Data: code=FWO7lxoRjc20cmIG2J1F4xWHu6ErL85RP1maAgNXAC00N5Ao10nxEFXdNkhsDvrdRQFBeF3x-H6xXFaD4jiunp7SUoedMvjfh8fNcfMbYYTnoCCGhf-4bJ4-m9PLOkieu_a3QrEZew02ybFblXP23wJccHLIqWUMtlwGWkwLu-tWrsIsIKIq6dXeFoJfxltc&redirect_uri=http://localhost&grant_type=authorization_code&client_id=1e4bea3c407e37e13e517ff74031217fd8196d08
2015-06-02 16:35:48.306 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:194 :: Starting the request with URL https://storeinbluemix.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/imf-authserver/authorization/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/token
2015-06-02 16:35:48.315 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136620] [DEBUG] [IMF_REQUEST] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest sendRequestToPath:path:withOptions:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:174 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x14e56c20>{number = 3, name = AFNetworking})
2015-06-02 16:35:48.335 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:215 :: Request Failed
2015-06-02 16:35:48.343 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:216 :: Response Status Code : 0
2015-06-02 16:35:48.351 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:217 :: Response Error : wl-oauth-prevent-redirect
2015-06-02 16:35:48.467 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:199 :: Request Success
2015-06-02 16:35:48.477 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:200 :: Response Status Code : 200
2015-06-02 16:35:48.485 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:201 :: Response Content : {"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImpwayI6eyJhb * BIN DATA * hmh10l6PcoUVnr6njYk99pj8g0JQjIIONtaXj5e6zc1-0jcue0n-2f8DrryXvTYcKrKxOAScc890uGQo5UBqneMjhn01DmWsyIZ561lj8uvXlg4SAj3XdoWW5CNx8fcH1DnrfiNVDAhJg","access_token":"e ** BIN DATA ** X9Ck91whdZyatn40t8ZTb7O3K31BA"}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.505 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[IMFAuthorizationRequest requestFinished:] in IMFAuthorizationRequest.m:341    :: Response Header: {
Connection = "Keep-Alive";
"Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Tue, 02 Jun 2015 14:35:42 GMT";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
"X-Backside-Transport" = "OK OK";
"X-Cf-Requestid" = "5007bbfb-e8f8-436c-6b26-dd9a99308ac0";
"X-Client-IP" = "79.254.2.52";
"X-Global-Transaction-ID" = 1597951457;
"X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0";
}
    Response Data:   {"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"id_token":"eyJ *** BIN DATA **** BA"}
Status code=200
2015-06-02 16:35:48.601 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:194 :: Starting the request with URL https://storeinbluemix.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/imfmobileanalytics/v1/receiver/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455
2015-06-02 16:35:48.611 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:194 :: Starting the request with URL https://storeinbluemix.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/imfmobileanalytics/v1/receiver/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455
2015-06-02 16:35:48.620 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] [INFO] [IMFData] Obtained authorization header.  Re-issueing request to https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb: 
2015-06-02 16:35:48.629 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136597] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataProtocol.sendRequestToProtectedResource: making HTTP request.    Details: 
 URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
 Method: PUT
 Headers:
 Authorization : Bearer eyJhbGci  * BIN DATA * vTYcKrKxOAScc890uGQo5UBqneMjhn01DmWsyIZ561lj8uvXlg4SAj3XdoWW5CNx8fcH1DnrfiNVDAhJg
2015-06-02 16:35:48.642 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager releaseCompletionHandlerQueue:error:] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:428 :: Completion handlers queue released.
2015-06-02 16:35:48.649 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF_OAUTH] -[IMFAuthorizationManager clearCompletionHandlerQueue] in IMFAuthorizationManager.m:437 :: Completion handler queue cleared
2015-06-02 16:35:48.798 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136600] [INFO] [IMFData] Response from server at https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
Http Status: 412
Response Body:
{
error = "file_exists";
reason = "The database could not be created, the file already exists.";
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.807 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136600] [INFO] [IMFData] Cloudant create remote database response: Remote DB URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
HTTP_Status: 412
JSON Body: {
error = "file_exists";
reason = "The database could not be created, the file already exists.";
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.816 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] CDTStore created successfully: automobiledb
2015-06-02 16:35:48.817 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] The self.datastore.name is automobiledb : 
2015-06-02 16:35:48.821 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136600] [INFO] [IMFData] CDTHttpHelper.sendHttpRequest:method:headers:payload:completionHandler: making HTTP request.  Details: 
URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/_set_permissions
Method: POST
Headers:
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
Body: 
{
access = members;
database = automobiledb;
identity = 707109936101050;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.828 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] INSIDE (Create remote store) the self.datastore is not NIL: automobiledb
2015-06-02 16:35:48.830 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] CDTDataObjectMapper is not NIL The description is: (<CDTDataObjectMapper: 0x14d81940>)
2015-06-02 16:35:48.834 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] [INFO] [IMFData] CDTHttpHelper.sendHttpRequest:method:headers:payload:completionHandler: making HTTP request.  Details: 
URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
Method: POST
Headers:
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
Body: 
{
"@datatype" = CalcData;
theCalcValue = "1+2=3";
theID = 12345;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.846 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataProtocol.sendRequestToProtectedResource: making HTTP request.   Details: 
URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/_set_permissions
Method: POST
Headers:
Authorization : Bearer eyJh ** BIN DATA ** fuvXlg4SAj3XdoWW5CNx8fcH1DnrfiNVDAhJg
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
Body: 
{
access = members;
database = automobiledb;
identity = 707109936101050;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.858 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] [INFO] [IMFData] IMFDataProtocol.sendRequestToProtectedResource: making HTTP request.   Details: 
 URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
 Method: POST
 Headers:
 Authorization : Bearer eyJhbGciOi  ** BIN DATA ** iNVDAhJg
Content-Type : application/json
Accept : application/json
Body: 
{
"@datatype" = CalcData;
theCalcValue = "1+2=3";
theID = 12345;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:48.987 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:199 ::  Request Success
2015-06-02 16:35:48.994 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:200 :: Response Status Code : 201
2015-06-02 16:35:48.999 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] [INFO] [IMFData] Response from server at https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/_set_permissions
Http Status: 200
Response Body:
{
message = "IMFCP022I: F\U00fcr den Benutzer 707109936101050 gibt es bereits die Berechtigung f\U00fcr die Datenbank automobiledb.";
status = OK;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:49.006 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:201 :: Response Content : {}
2015-06-02 16:35:49.014 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] [INFO] [IMFData] Set permissions response: Remote Index URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/_set_permissions
HTTP_Status: 200
JSON Body: {
message = "IMFCP022I: F\U00fcr den Benutzer 707109936101050 gibt es bereits die Berechtigung f\U00fcr die Datenbank automobiledb.";
status = OK;
}
2015-06-02 16:35:49.024 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136600] No ERROR Description available - Cloudant User Permission OK
2015-06-02 16:35:49.025 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136600] BOOLEAN CHECK: 'success == true' Cloudant User Permission
2015-06-02 16:35:49.040 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:215 :: Request Failed
2015-06-02 16:35:49.050 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:216 :: Response Status Code : 500
2015-06-02 16:35:49.059 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [DEBUG] [IMF] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:217 :: Response Error : Expected status code in (200-299), got 500
2015-06-02 16:35:49.081 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136563] [OCLogger] Request to send analytics data has failed.
2015-06-02 16:35:49.240 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] [INFO] [IMFData] Response from server at https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
Http Status: 201
Response Body:
{
id = 32d92f7601ef00e7a95df62a4c2983c0;
ok = 1;
rev = "1-dcf9fa05185806284b4d73996540e7b2";
}
2015-06-02 16:35:49.251 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136632] [INFO] [IMFData] Cloudant create document response. Remote URL: https://mobile.eu-gb.bluemix.net/imfdata/api/v1/apps/902f719f-f8a7-449f-ad4b-d50d48e68455/automobiledb
HTTP_Status: 201
JSON Body: {
id = 32d92f7601ef00e7a95df62a4c2983c0;
ok = 1;
rev = "1-dcf9fa05185806284b4d73996540e7b2";
}
2015-06-02 16:35:49.261 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] CHECK SAVE during the setup CALC DATA -- START ---
2015-06-02 16:35:49.262 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] The saved revision: <CalcData: 0x14e92a60>
2015-06-02 16:35:49.263 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] Data Saved: Value: 1+2=3 ID: 12345
2015-06-02 16:35:49.263 StoreInBlueMix[5618:2136601] CHECK SAVE during the setup CALC DATA -- END ---
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs, it looks like it works.  Based on your log statements, I see the following:

```
Print "ERROR: OK    Cloudant User Permission", if error is nil.
Print "SUCCESS: Error Cloudant User Permission", if success is YES/TRUE.
```

The log statements only show the `create` db and set `permissions` snippets,  I can't comment on the `save Object` until logs are provided.

Comment: Hello Naeem, Hello Kevan, now I am able to save a object ... but only, if I do not split the database tasks in different operations. I updated the entry based on this result and I added some more meaningful DEBUG comments. Thanks for your feedback Thomas